# web-audio api -- iPad4 safari out of tune?

Tags: web-audio-api

I have a simple synth that plays a 100hz tone using an OscillatorNode. My synth is about a whole step flat on safari iPad 4 ios 7.1.1, compared to all the other browsers I've tried (chrome iPad 4, safari ipad 2 ios 7.1.1, safari iPhone 5, chrome and safari on my mac). I've verified that the sample rate of the out-of-tune browser, iPad 4 safari, is 44100hz. The in-tune browsers report the same sample rate, 4400hz.

My code is pretty simple and I don't see how this could be a programming error on my part. Especially considering the iPad 2 and iPad 4 are running the same OS (and presumably the same version of safari). It seems like there's something weird, low-level and hardware-dependent going on.

Is this a known issue? If so, is there any way to test for it or work around it?

===== edit ========

Here's an example (safari only) -- dead simple oscillator test. Plays at one pitch on my iPhone 5s, a different pitch on my iPad 4. http://www.morganpackard.com/webaudio_test/OscillatorTest.html

```
      var context = new webkitAudioContext();
      var osc = context.createOscillator();
      osc.connect(context.destination);
      osc.frequency.value = 440;
      osc.start(0);
```

Comment: Could you post your sample code?

Comment: @cwilso Will try to post sample code tonight.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to one device playing at 44.1kHz and the other playing at 48kHz.  There is probably a browser bug preventing the change of sample rate, and the subsequent misreporting of sample rate.

Chrome on Android has a similar issue where the record and playback sample rates must be identical.  Since this doesn't typically happen when recording from the on-board microphone, for while it would seem that recording audio was always silent.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable hypothesis to me. I think I could test for this by checking if the context's current time is correct, or if it's lagging behind the regular javascript clock (assuming the audio context clock works by counting samples). Any other ideas about how I might test for this bug? I don't imagine there's a way for javascript to query the hardware sample rate.

Comment: @morgancodes Can you play a beep every second or so, and listen for them to quickly fall out of phase?  Technically, your test of them being out of pitch is already a pretty good test.  You could measure this difference and see if it equates to 44.1kHz/48kHz.

Comment: that sounds like a good demo, to illustrate that there's a bug. I'd be interested in designing a runtime test/workaround, so that when I encounter one of these devices that's out of tune, I can adjust on the fly. I'm specifically interested in building an application where multiple devices play audio in the same physical space, and it would be a bummer if every tenth device was irreparably out of tune.

Comment: @morgancodes You could just stick to performing Steve Reich pieces.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouYiTiiY3vg  :-)

Comment: you joke, but you're pretty damn close actually :)